# mongoDB $set problem with using value of document's key/another fields value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem with update and set in mongoDB.(MongoDB shell version v4.2.6)
I have a collection that contains documents like:

```
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ec6b069a8640000b1002012"),
        "name": "MS WINDOWS DSP 10 HOME 32-BIT ENG",
        "brand": "MICROSOFT",
        "date_added": NumberInt("1590079220"),
        "supplier": {
            "name": "dsfgdft",
            "product_id": "00-01-901-091"
        },
    ...
}
```

When i try to add a new field to all the documents in the collection, with the following command:

```
db.products.update({},{$set:{search_stems:"$name"}},{multi:true})
```

The documents do not get the value of the `$name` for the key  `search_stems` it just adds $name as search_stems value

```
     {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ec6b069a8640000b1002012"),
        "name": "MS WINDOWS DSP 10 HOME 32-BIT ENG",
        "brand": "MICROSOFT",
        "date_added": NumberInt("1590079220"),
        "supplier": {
            "name": "dsfgdft",
            "product_id": "00-01-901-091"
        },
    ...
"search_stem":"$name"
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

I have read the following

[Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

but it is not getting the direct value of a field from document they use $concat after $set

Comment: what is your MongoDB server version ? after connecting to DB just do `db.version`

Comment: The server is MongoDB server version: 4.2.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field) that's exactly what you're looking for..

Comment: No it is not exactly what i'm looking for i have seen that answer but i simply want to use the value of the $name ... and not to use any extra method like $concat etc...

Comment: that concat is for additional task as per that questions need, but the concept is same using *aggregation pipeline in updates*..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query which uses aggregation pipeline in [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) :

```
db.products.updateMany({},[ { $set: { search_stems : "$name" } } ])
```

In aggregation we can refer to a field using `$`, So we're wrapping your update operation in an array `[]` to say it's an aggregation pipeline, Using `$set` operator which is an alias to `$addFields` in aggregation we're able to set `search_stems` field's  value taken out from `name` field.

Aggregation in updates is introduced since `4.2`, prior to that if you do `search_stems:"$name"` it means you're assigning string value `$name` to a field called `search_stems`. As a note you don't need use `{multi:true}` option with `.update()` instead use `.updateMany()`.

Comment: Ok this solved my problem thank you for the clarification & effort